# Identifying http request with KERBEROS from Java runing on Linux

Tags: java, linux, single-sign-on, kerberos

I have some environment with both Linux and Windows servers. Authentication is handled by Kerberos. I want to make some JAVA code which automatically authenticates the http requests it makes as being done by the logged in user executing the program.

For example, if I have this code:

```
CloseableHttpClient winHttpclient = WinHttpClients.createDefault();

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://mykerberos/endpoint");

winHttpclient.execute(httpget).getEntity();
```

when I execute it from windows, it works out of the box. I am identified by http://mykerberos/endpoint and get the response.

Now, I want to do the same from a Linux server.
I found a couple of proposal, like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/lab/part6.html#Proxy_Authentication but it is not what I look for as it requires my credentials: from Windows, I do not even have to pass them.

Does someone know how I can achieve this ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your Windows credentials are (I guess) a Kerberos ticket granted by an Active Directory server; the web server is also (I guess) using AD for authentication, that's what the SPNego protocol is used for. But what are your Linux credentials? Didi you login against a local Linux account, or against the same AD account you use in Windows (with binding done by SSSD or Centrify for example)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. You are right, when we log into windows, we get a kerberos ticket, and yes the web server is using our AD server for authentication. Authentication is done using the SPNego protocol. We use the same accounts for Linux. I do not know which tool is used to bind them to our AD. I checked and when I log in a linux host, _klist_ returns me a ticket.

Comment: If you have a valid TGT in your Kerberos ticket cache, then any decent HTTP client (i.e. that supports SPNego) should be able to connect. Including `curl` command-line utility with `--negotiate -u :`

Comment: Caveat: Apache HTTP client has a bad rep when it comes to SPNego; when developing a Java app, stick to the default libraries.

Comment: I have tried `curl -u : --negotiate http://...` succesfully.
In Java, I tried to follow: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/lab/part6.html and I have this error:
_Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache true useKeyTab false doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is false principal is null tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Acquire TGT from Cache
>>>KinitOptions cache name is /tmp/krb5cc_0
Principal is null
null credentials from Ticket Cache_

Comment: I got it working: I was using Java 6 instead of Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/lab/part6.html is working fine when using a proper version of Java (it works for java 8 but not java 6).